# Reading files from sub directories of SFTP using VFS transport in WSO2

Tags: vfs, wso2-esb

We have a scenario in which we need to process all the files in current folder and all the sub folders in it. The sub folders name is dynamic.

Is this possible to achieve using vfs in wso2?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible with the default implementation of vfs. You need to customize the source of vfs transport to support this.

Comment: Thanks Martin.. I have written custom schedule task to achieve the same